# How can I get the 80 Coins & 1000 Stars Achievement?

Tags: achievements, geometry-dash

In Geometry Dash you can Unlock new icons with achievements. Some of those are "Collect 80 Secret Coins" or "Collect 1000 Stars". Now when I look at the Levels I only see 15. Each of them has only 3 Coins and gives between 1 and 14 Stars.

So how exactly can I get the achievements with 1000 Stars and 80 Coins if there are only 114 Stars and 45 Coins available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get more stars by completing user-generated levels. Tap on the right button in the menu and go to "Featured" to get started.

You can earn more secret coins by completing mappacks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to complete user created levels to earn more stars and complete map pack to earn stars AND secret coins.

Answer (score -3):

Coins are in normal levels, usually hidden, but you can get stars in any level, depending on the difficulty.

Comment: Could you add some more information if possible? Maybe some suggestions as to where to find them?